# Render Content Labels and Values

Tags: theming, entities, 8

In my node--content_type.html.twig template file, I can output both the label AND value of a field by using:

```
{{ content.field_title }}
```

I can also render just the label of a field with:

```
{{ content.field_title['#title'] }}
```

So far, so good.

However, how can I output only the VALUE of a field using the content array? I've tried:

```
{{ content.field_title['#value'] }}
```

And:

```
{{ content.field_title.value }}
```

To no avail.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the field value **without the label**:

`{{ content.field_name[0] }}`

> #### BONUS
>
> If your field allows for multiple values, just increase the 0 to get the
>   other values.
>
> `{{ content.field_name[1] }}` `{{ content.field_name[2] }}` ... and so
>   on.

Answer (score 2):

I've created this module that lets you print the field label and field value individually: https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/sutharsan/2763183

`<strong>{{ content.field_name|field_label }}</strong>: {{ content.field_name|field_value }}`

Let me know if it is useful to you I will promote it to a full project.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `{{ dump(your_field) }}` which debug show all value in field. Remember you need setting [Debugging Twig template](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates)